# I'm having trouble displaying polygons in the mapbox map

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

Good afternoon, I'm having trouble displaying polygons in the mapbox map.

To put in context, I am using React, I have two key components, PolygonsViewer and PolygonsEditor.

PolygonsEditor only displays when the user's polygons are to be edited. It creates a Drawing and allows to do so. On the other hand, the PolygonsViewer only creates a layer with the area color defined for each user polygon.

This is the code of my PolygonsViewer.tsx:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
// Contexts
import { usePolygons } from "../../context/PolygonsContext";
import { Map } from "mapbox-gl";
// Utils
import createFlyingAreas from "../../utils/polygons/createFlyingAreas";

type Props = {
  map: React.RefObject<Map>;
  location?: "station" | "flight";
};

const PolygonsViewer = ({ map, location = "station" }: Props) => {
  const { areas, ROI, piles } = usePolygons();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (location == "station") {
      createFlyingAreas({ map, areas });
    } else {
      console.log(ROI);
    }
  }, [areas, ROI, piles]);

  return null;
};

export default PolygonsViewer;
```

When the createFlyingAreas() function is called, that is where we create the layers. The code is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
// Context
import { Map } from "mapbox-gl";
import { FlyingArea } from "../../../../contexts/interfaces";

type Props = {
  map: React.RefObject<Map>;
  areas: FlyingArea[];
};

const createFlyingAreas = ({ map, areas }: Props) => {
  let i = 0;
  areas.map((area: FlyingArea) => {
    const layerExists = map.current!.getLayer(`area-${i}`);
    if (!layerExists) {
      const coordinates = area.boundary.map((coord) => [coord[1], coord[0]]);
      map.current!.addLayer({
        id: `area-${i}`,
        type: "fill",
        source: {
          type: "geojson",
          data: {
            type: "Feature",
            geometry: {
              type: "Polygon",
              coordinates: [coordinates],
            },
            properties: {},
          },
        },
        layout: {},
        paint: {
          "fill-color": area.color,
          "fill-opacity": 0.5,
        },
      });
    }
    i = i + 1;
  });
};

export default createFlyingAreas;
```

This doesn't show anything on the map, but by commenting, the layers do exist. Would anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

I am trying to display some areas as polygons on the MapBox map. The result is that it creates well the sources and layers but it doesn't show anything.